# Does there exist a problem that is hard to do in parallel?

Tags: complexity-theory, linear-programming, factoring, primes

I am looking for a workload which is hard to paralellise/distribute between multiple machines.

For example, integer factorization does not go 10 times faster if you have 10 machines to split the load, but is there a better example?

Comment: Your "EDIT:" question seems rather *less* technical but also seems to be a separate question.

Comment: Are we talking linear programming, or integer-linear programming? These problems have vastly different complexity.

Comment: @jmite I have no experience with both, so I have no clue

Comment: @DavidRicherby Why is that a seperate question?

Comment: @Muis Your main question is about a specific algorithmic problem; the edited extra question is about practical programming on multiprocessor systems.

Comment: *"integer factorization does not go 10 times faster if you have 10 machines to split the load"* - I think you're making an assumption here that isn't quite right.  In fact, the best algorithms for integer factorization *do* parallelize quite well (the sieving step is specifically designed to admit parallelization).

Comment: Please decide what you are asking.  Are you asking about (a) whether linear programming is parallelizable, or (b) whether integer linear programming is parallelizable, or (c) whether there exists any problem that is not parallelizable, or (d) what types of code tend not to parallelize well?  Those are 3 very different questions.  You need to pick 1.  And then tell us what research you've done (we expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking).  Also, question (d) is probably too broad, so if that's what you want, try to narrow down your question.

Comment: @D.W. It was C, so i edited it.

Comment: The question is OK for me, except for the fact that one comment states that the assertion about integer factorization is not quite right. Maybe it should be removed or better supported. cc @D.W.

Answer (score 2):

Linear programming is **P**-complete with respect to either logspace or **NC** reductions (I'm not sure which).  As such, it's unlikely to be efficiently parallelizable because, for either kind of reductions, that would imply that **P$\,=\,$NC**. It's generally believed that **P$\,\neq\,$NC**.

There's more information on Wikipedia's [**P**-completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete) page.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know if this also goes true for 'Integer Linear Programming'?

Comment: No, ILP is **NP**-complete: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns). Please do some basic research with a search engine before asking other people to help!

Comment: Im not to lazy too Google, but you cannot assume everyone has the education to understand math-related wikipedia articles.

Comment: @Muis OK. From the fact that you're asking questions about linear programming, I'd assumed that you did have enough mathematical knowledge to understand those pages. Feel free to ask about any of those things, too (though they should go in separate questions and you should check whether our [reference material](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions) covers what you need).

Comment: Well, be careful with the assumptions here.  In this answer "parallelizable" refers to a theoretical version of that notion, which might not correspond well to what people mean in practice by "parallelizable" (for example if LP was 50x faster when run on a cluster with 100 machines, that wouldn't contradict any known theoretical result).

Comment: The theoretical results are probably better interpreted as saying that it's not "super-parallelizable", where super-parallelizable means parallelizable to an incredible degree.  But problems can still allow some degree of parallelization even if they're not super-paralellizable.  So the theoretical results aren't quite as definitive as they might appear at first glance.

Comment: FWIW, NC has little (if anything) to with how well a problem can be solved in parallel on real machines.

Comment: @Muis It is fair to assume that a person asking a mathematical (or close to that) question will already have learned or at least be willing to learn some basics.

Comment: @Raphael Then there should be a site: beginner-math.stackexchange.com, because until today I had no notion about what LP, ILP, NP, or even P was. So I how am I suppposed to ask high-quality question?

Comment: @Muis I don't understand. You asked a question that was explicitly about parallelizability of linear programming. Now, you've edited it to remove all trace of that and are claiming that you don't even know what linear programming is. What gives?

Comment: @Muis You posed a question using lots of jargon that (apparently) let people to believe you knew what you were talking about. Maybe it's my foul mood at the moment, but this seems fair to me.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I was forced to edit it to get it reopened, not my choice.